# Using Regex, how can I get the words "músicas" or "áudio" in a sentence?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'd like to check a sentence in JavaScript. I'm using Web Speech API in Portuguese (PT-BR) by Google. So code follows:

```
[...]

// Writes the spoken sentence on a field
document.getElementById('text').innerHTML = result;

// Should check whether "músicas" is in sentence or not
if (/músicas/g.test(result) == true)
{
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Inside sentence";
}
else
{
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Not inside sentence";
}

[...]
```

The variable **result** stores the spoken sentence in Portuguese, for example, **Eu gosto de músicas** (Which means **I like musics**). Then, the conditions should check, but it's not working with accentuations.

By the way, if I check something without accentuation, such as **/fotos/g**, it works perfectly!

Can anybody help me with this probably simple Regex issue?

Thank you.

Comment: Your code works fine.

Comment: Did you bother to even test your code before posting here?

Comment: No. I already tried this before and wasn't working. The problem it's because the variable result isn't a simple string, it's a particular string used in real-time by API and wasn't working without unicode as you suggested. Worked using "\u00FA" only. Got it?

Comment: Thanks Mr. Biegeleisen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To match accented vowels in a JavaScript regex, we can use the unicode character class:

```
if (/m[\u00FA]sicas/g.test(result) == true) {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "Inside sentence";
}
```

You can refer [here](https://emw3.com/unicode-accents.html) for a table of accented characters and their Unicode equivalents.

Note that as others have mentioned, in pure JavaScript you do not need Unicode classes for this, but apparently you have an application which requires this.


## Demo

Comment: This is not exactly required. `/músicas/g.test("it contains músicas text")` returns true.